# jQuery .hasClass() failed for tab changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML structure :

```
<div class="tab-pane slide-left padding-20" id="tab1">...</div>
<div class="tab-pane slide-left padding-20 active" id="tab2">...</div>
<div class="tab-pane slide-left padding-20" id="tab3">...</div>
```

current active tab will have `active` class, that's why, I want to create conditional function to handle some variables when `tab2` is active using this code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($("#tab2").hasClass("active")) {
            alert ("yes it's active!!");
        }
    });
</script>
```

but it's not working. no alert message shows up when `#tab2` is active. how to make this works? thank you.

Please note : tab changes doesn't reload all the page.

Comment: Are the tab changes without a page reload? The `.ready` function only fires once, when the page is loaded

Comment: Your code seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/dgrur6xq

Comment: @devqon : yes. tab changes without document reload.

Comment: @GG. : it works when the `#tab2` has active class since the beginning. but when it start with `#tab1`, then I go to `#tab2`, then it won't start the alert. tab changes doesn't reload the whole page.

Comment: Then check the class when you change the tabs

Comment: see @devqon's comment, the `.ready` event is only fired once: when the page is loaded. As a result, with your code, if `#tab2` doesn't have the `active` class when the page is loaded, then your alert will never be fired. If you want that to be dynamic, you'll have to listen to some events. I'm thinking listening to the clicks on your `.tab-panes`.

Comment: You probably want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hxcx1pyq/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that.

```
$('.tab-pane').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        alert($(this).attr('id') + " it's active!!");
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dgrur6xq/2/)**</kbd>

Or directly:

```
$('.tab-pane.active').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id') + " it's active!!");
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dgrur6xq/3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery UI, you can try this

var active = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active" );

This function will work if you want to dome action based on that

```
$('.selector').tabs({
                    activate: function(event ,ui){
                        //console.log(event);
                        console.log(ui.newTab.index());
                    }
});
```